# SonarQune complains _equalsCalc variable generated from wsdl file is not transient or serializable

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, wsdl2java

Hi i am new to wsdl to java conversion as it is really old. I am currently working on SonarQube issues where it throws "Make _equalsCalc transient or Serializable" error. Since these are auto-generated java files,i am not able to make the changes in the java file. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

```
private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;
public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof PropertyData)) return false;
    PropertyData other = (PropertyData) obj;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (__equalsCalc != null) {
        return (__equalsCalc == obj);
    }
    __equalsCalc = obj;
    boolean _equals;
    _equals = true && 
        ((this.key==null && other.getKey()==null) || 
         (this.key!=null &&
          this.key.equals(other.getKey()))) &&
        ((this.value==null && other.getValue()==null) || 
         (this.value!=null &&
          this.value.equals(other.getValue())));
    __equalsCalc = null;
    return _equals;
}
```

Comment: Tell sonar to ignore generated code

Answer (score 0):

In WSDL file definition, please add the following to generate serialized object.

```
<jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```